# Only variables should be passed by reference on line 44

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if(isset($_POST['l_login']))
    {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM librarian WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;");
        $query->bind_param("ss", $_POST['l_user'], sha1($_POST['l_pass']));  //line44
        $query->execute();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query->get_result()) != 1)
            echo error_without_field("Invalid username/password combination");
        else
        {
```

the code is not working Only variables should be passed by reference on line 44

Answer (score 0):

`sha1($_POST['l_pass'])` is a function call, not a variable. You can't pass its result by reference. Simply call the function beforehand and assign its result to a variable - you can then pass this to bind_param():

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM librarian WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;");
$pass_hashed = sha1($_POST['l_pass'])
$query->bind_param("ss", $_POST['l_user'], $pass_hashed);
$query->execute();
```

---

N.B. SHA-1 is [widely known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) to be cryptographically broken and insecure - this has been the case for some years now (at the time of writing). You would be stronly advised to stop using it and switch to a more up to date, secure algorithm for hashing your passwords. You can learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)